# how can I choose particular lines from a file by using a second file

Tags: perl

I am trying to filter a file (trying to find the best blast hits) by using a second file.
The file that I want to filter looks like this:

```
conserved1      chr22   100.00  92      0       0       1       92      19679676                        19679767        2e-44    182
.....................
```

The second file (which is the first input in my script) that I’m using is like this:

```
conserved1      92
conserved2      76
.....................
```

(the first column is the name of my ‘item’ which is exactly with the first column of the previous file, and the second column is the size).

I stored the second file in a hash in order to connect the first file with the sizes of the conserved elements and to filter only the lines which the size (4th column) be the 70% of the size (from the 2nd file).

I wrote this script for that purpose, it works but it prints each chosen line more than once.
How can I fix this?

```
my $size_file = $ARGV[0];
my $alignment_file = $ARGV[1];

open my $con_info, $size_file or die "Could not open $size_file: $!";

my %hash;
while (<$con_info>)
{
chomp;
my ($key, $val) = split /\t/;
$hash{$key} .= exists $hash{$key} ? "$val" : $val;
}
#print "# %hash\n", Dump \%hash;
#print %hash;
#print "@{[%hash]}";

close $con_info;

open my $al_info, $alignment_file or die "Could not open $alignment_file: $!";

while (my $line = <$al_info>)  {
    chomp;
    my@data = split('\t', $line);
    my $con_name = $data[0];
    my $evalue = $data[10];
    my $percent = $data[2];
    my $length = $data[3];
   # print $con_name. "\n";

foreach my $key (keys %hash) {
    if ($key  == $con_name) {
       #print "key: $key, value: $hash{$key}\n";
            if ($evalue <= 1e-4 && $length >= 0.70 * $hash{$key}) {
                    print $line;
            }

    }
   }
}
```

The output should be the first file (the file which is at the first code box) but with less lines, the lines that passes through the last if condition. 
Thank you very- very much for your help!!!

Comment: how output should look like?

Comment: the output will be like the first file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($key  == $con_name)
```

should be

```
if ($key eq $con_name)
```

as this should be string comparison.

And you don't really need `foreach` loop, just to pick one particular key:

```
while (my $line = <$al_info>)  {

    chomp($line);
    my @data = split('\t', $line);
    # my $con_name = $data[0];
    # my $percent = $data[2];
    # my $length = $data[3];
    # my $evalue = $data[10];
    my ($con_name, $percent, $length, $evalue) = @data[0,2,3,10];

   # print $con_name. "\n"; 
   if ($evalue <= 1e-4 && $length >= 0.70 * $hash{$con_name}) {
            print $line;
   }
}
```

Comment: the hash takes the values from the second file, the file with the sizes. So by giving the $con_name into the hash it peaks the right value?
Also Im using the == because it didn't work with eq, and I don't know why.

Comment: @Vasilis, yes but `$con_name` is string like `conserved1` and `eq` is operator for testing string equality

Comment: but in your solution actually I don't need this if condition.
right?

Comment: @Vasilis right, you don't. can you `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%hash;` before this while loop?

Comment: Yes, to check content of hash.

Comment: ok, you're right. I will check it. To tell you the truth Im a little bit confused about the way that Dumper works.Im new in this field...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37283/discussion-between-vasilis-and-mpapec)